# Ingress Nginx: X-Forwarded-Host set as host and routed through to an ingress that does not match

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

On an Amazon EKS Kubernetes cluster, I have [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) setup with the configmap annotation, setting: `use-forwarded-headers: "true"`. This "works", in that `X-Forwarded-` headers are translated when we want them to be.

However, if we manually set an `X-Forwarded-Host` header on a request, then the request is routed through to the application matching the original host, but with the host set as the manually set `X-Forwarded-Host` header:

```
curl -H "X-Forwarded-Host: www.evil-or-malicious-something.com" https://www.domain-x.com/
```

Inspecting the headers for the application shows that it sees the host as `www.evil-or-malicious-something.com`, it does NOT see `www.domain-x.com` in any headers whatsoever.

What I would like and expect to happen here is that the ingress controller does *not* route the request to the application. It is setting the host header to one thing, but matching the ingress host on another.

If this is deliberate behaviour, is there any way I can configure it to behave as I'd like?

(I have done much googling of issues around `use-forwarded-headers: "true"` and X-Forwarded-Host but nothing coming back with a solution for this particular issue).

Comment: I think, to *potentially* answer my own question, that *use-forwarded-headers: "true"* should NOT really be the case here. This should only be used when the ingress LB is behind another proxy. In our case, we have multiple domains and some may need some config tweak to mean that we don't need this.

I still find this situation strange though, curious to hear thoughts from an ingress protocol expert.